# I don't understand what's the different between a '&' in and out of a class object's variable parentheses

Tags: c++

```
class thing {
public:
int value1 = 5;
void display(){cout << value2 << endl;}
private:
int value2 = 77;
};
int main()
{
thing A;
cout << A.value1 << endl;
cout << A.value2 << endl;
cout << *(&A.value1 + 1) << endl;
A.display();
cin >>  *(&A.value1 + 1);
A.display();
return 0;
}
```

Here lies the class, and i don't really understand the difference between
*(&A.value1 + 1) and  *(&A.value1 + 1)

Comment: You asked the difference between `*(&A.value1 + 1)` and `*(&A.value1 + 1)`. Those are both the same, so there is no difference... 99% sure they're both undefined behavior, so they might invoke nasal demons, but they're clearly the same thing.

Comment: There is no difference.  `&A.value1` gives the address of where `A.value1` is stored.  Then you look at the value in the next array location which is not allowed because `A.value1`  isn't an array.  After that the compiler is free to do anything it wants including doing what you expect or something you didn't expect.

Comment: Maybe you need to explain why you think there is a difference.  What output did the program create that made you wonder?  I'm just asking because the program doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: As an example of undefined behaviour doing something you didn't expect, have a look at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: you are right Jerry Jeremiah, the output is just same, the output on my side is  5 77 77, which are the values of value1 and value2, then I input a whatever number and A.display() display the number i just input.